# What could be wrong with a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I couldn't make head or tail of this: I have a function that reads a bunch of csv files from a S3 bucket, concats them and returns the DataFrame:

```
def create_df():
  df1 = pd.read_csv(s3_path + 'file_1.csv')
  df2 = pd.read_csv(s3_path + 'file_2.csv')

  return pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
```

My second function performs aggregation:

```
def aggregate_values(df):
  columns = ['col_c', 'col_d']
  new_df = df.groupby(columns, as_index=False) \
    .agg({'col_a': 'sum', 'col_b': 'mean'})

  return new_df
```

The function aggregate_values fails due to an Out of Memory error.

```
df = create_df()

# OOM error !!!
new_df = aggregate_values(df)
```

The curious thing is if I write out the DataFrame to my local file system and then read it back in, the aggregation works without a glitch on the new DataFrame.

```
df = create_df()
df.to_csv('path_to_store/f.csv', index=False)

df2 = pd.read_csv('path_to_store/f.csv')

# works fine!!!
new_df = aggregate_values(df2)
```

My guess is that there is something wrong with the DataFrame that's returned by create_df(). By writing it out and reading it back in Pandas somehow corrects the problem. But I want to find out exactly what's wrong with the DataFrame.

How do I go about debugging this problem?

**Edited**

I have 32G RAM on the machine running the code. The DataFrame has about 2 million records and takes about 0.5G storage and memory space.

Comment: it doesn't have to be problem with dataframe generathed by other process but simply other process keep some memory and it needs also memory to send data to main process - and all this use too many memory.

Comment: That is not the case here: the other process is a function I invoke in my code. If I invoke the function to get the dataframe, then perform the aggregation, I got a OOM error. However if I invoke the function to get the dataframe, write the dataframe out to file system, read it back in, then perform the aggregation, it would work fine.

Comment: I can't see your code but when you write to file then it may remove from memory unused elements and make space. Maybe you assign new value to some variable and this can inform Garbage Collector  to remove some elements from memory.

Comment: I edited my post adding the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and it turned out to be a good one.

One of the columns in the DataFrame returned by create_df() has dtype category. Not sure how this came about as it is meant to be string. This column is used in the grouper for the aggregation. By writing the DataFrame to the local file system and then reading it back in, the column got re-interpreted correctly by Pandas as string.

With the correct data type, the aggregation runs and returns quickly and there is no memory issue whatsoever. I do not understand why grouping on a categorical column would cause OOM error --- that is a topic for another day.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't comment on your memory size,
nor the size of the .CSV's or data frames.
But I can hazard some guesses.
I have a few observations:

1. After concatenating, you have an opportunity to nuke df1 & df2. Simply assign `None` to them, to reclaim some RAM.
2. The .groupby() possibly accepted dense numpy arrays and produced higher-overhead sparse arrays. You might want to look into that.
3. Computing the mean might have turned e.g. `int8` into `float64`, which clearly would consume more space.
4. Here's the biggest item: .groupby() likely returned a (mutable) view rather than a brand new numpy array. Roundtrip to the filesystem fixes that, but a simple .copy() would have the same effect, so try that.

Please post an answer here, letting us know how it went.

Comment: I am not so sure RAM is the problem here, as evidenced by my second workflow where I wrote the dataframe to the local file system and read it back. If anything the second workflow would use more RAM than the 1st wokrflow.  The second workflow did not have to get rid of df1 and df2 (as suggested by your first comment), and it uses the same groupby (as suggested by your second comment). I am not convinced that the RAM is the problem here at all.